# What is the name of someone who does not know how to use a computer or the web?

Tags: terminology, users, web, novice-users, audience

People who cannot read or write are named "illiterate".

Does a word exist to qualify someone in the same position but about using a computer or a web application?

This term would be really usefull to qualify an important population requiering specific attention from us to ease the access of our applications.

**PS**: A neologism for "computer illiterate" would be perfect. (Something based on "iwebitracy", "incomputracy", ...)

**PS2**: There is no jugement about this "population" (read it as the statistical term) which we all come from; "incomputracy" or illiteracy are not a disease or a deficiency. They are only a lack of practice and experience. They both result in a blocking issue for people trying to reach new strata of our universe: job, knowledge, etc. We have a word for the analogic word (illiteracy). Why is there no word for the digital world?

Comment: Have you thought about just using the term 'novice'?

Comment: No, because I think it does not match entierly the definition. :)

Comment: Back in my day we just called them "noobs".

Comment: . . . . . "mom"

Comment: Seemed like I'm reading english.SE

Comment: Offline ?  ( Newbies were people, who knew enough to turn the computer on, but then blundered around accidently deleting the contents of the c: drive :-) )

Comment: How about "The 99%"?

Answer (score 8):

The general term I've heard is "computer illiterate"

Comment: That's exactly this. But does a neologism exist for that?

Answer (score 8):

***Novice users*** comes to mind, but you can also use terms like *non-tech savvy*, *computer illiterate*, or just *new computer user*.  But this doesn't specify the level they are at.

For situations like this I would **create a persona** that more fully represents the demographic that you want to refer to, and then refer to that persona instead of trying to name a category.

Assuming your persona was named Mary:
"Would Mary find this easy to use?" is more useful than "Would a computer illiterate person find this easy to use?"

Comment: +1 This is a really good term, since illiterate would be going too far. These users can read and write, so they are not illiterate per se. [Web Illiteracy: How Much Is Your Fault?](http://readwrite.com/2010/03/15/web_illiteracy_how_much_is_your_fault)

Comment: I think it is important to have a neologism/word to qualify a "computer illiterate". It is not pejorative but a reality especially when dealing with mainstream web applications.

Comment: @Toto How do you define that level? Even in reading, illiterate doesn't mean that you can't read at all, just that your level is below a set minimum. So what would the minimum level be?

Comment: The real question is how we name someone who does not know how to use a computer or who does not know how to use the web at all? Speaking about were we set the level for "iwebitracy" or "incomputracy" would be a debate and against SE terms. ;)

Comment: "Novice User" is the best term. It is important to remember that users are multi-dimensional; they may not be experts on computers, but they are good at other tasks. You have to focus on the person first, then the technology.

Comment: A "novice user" is a way to general term void of sense. It can be used for anything. I am looking for a specific term. :) Illiterate are also good at other tasks. It is not the topic. :)

Answer (score 4):

A **luddite** is described by Urban Dictionary as

> One who fears technology (or new technology, as they seem pleased with
>   how things currently are...why can't everything just be the same?)

Comment: _"The Luddites were 19th-century English textile artisans who violently protested against the machinery introduced during the Industrial Revolution that made it possible to replace them with less-skilled, low-wage labourers, leaving them without work._ - [Luddite on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luddite)

Comment: Yes, and it is frequently used in IT circles as a term for those who can't or won't adapt to new technology. Normally politicians.

Comment: It seems to me a luddite have an intent or opinion about the technology. One who is positive towards new technology (say computers) could still be a total novice. I'm not saying it isn't frequently used, just that there could be a better word for it.

Answer (score 1):

**Neophyte** is similar to @GrahamBorland's answer in that the [official definitions](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/neophyte) don't really give it justice:

> 1. a beginner or novice: He's a neophyte at chess.
> 2. Roman Catholic Church . a novice.
> 3. a person newly converted to a belief, as a heathen, heretic, or nonbeliever; proselyte.
> 4. Primitive Church. a person newly baptized.

The way it's almost always used in my experience, a neophyte is like a newbie in that they don't know something, but different in that they *want to learn*.

It has the bonus of sounding all hackery to someone whose only such knowledge is [CSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSI_%28franchise%29).

Answer (score 1):

In Dutch we have the word 'digibeet', in analogy with 'analfabeet', e.g. the English analphabetic.

I guess 'digibetic' would be the English version, and would perhaps be a good word for this. However, for now computer illiterate as mentioned in the other answers would be the best term.